# Use native iOS compass within an app

Tags: objective-c, ios, native, compass-geolocation

Is it possible to use the native compass that iOS has within my own application?  Or do I need to draw and animate my own compass?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no native compass `UIView`. In order to use the magnetometer, you'll have to use CoreLocation and the following delegate method:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
             didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

to rotate a UIView to point North (bearingView is a UIImageView):

```
float heading = newHeading.magneticHeading; //in degrees
float headingDegrees = (heading*M_PI/180); //assuming needle points to top of iphone. convert to radians
self.bearingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(headingDegrees);
```

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about the native compass UIView.  I'll wait a little to see if anyone else disagrees.  Certainly yes, didUpdateHeading is the way to update whatever image i choose to draw. Thanks so much.

Comment: Keller - since nobody else has contradicted you, I'll take your answer as the correct one.  Thanks mate.

Comment: No problem. To create a compass view that points north, simply create a "compass needle" graphic and rotate it via it's transform. See my Edit.

Comment: Here is a full tutorial on how to implement this if anyone was wondering: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/01/10/how-to-create-a-compass-in-iphone/

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw  http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/01/10/how-to-create-a-compass-in-iphone/   link not working. 
Please help me to create compass in IOS objective-c

Comment: @DipankiJadav We are in luck! Archive.org has a copy of the site from before it went down!  https://web.archive.org/web/20150421132328/http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/01/10/how-to-create-a-compass-in-iphone