# How to rotate Google Map according to Device Compass Value?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

i am using Latest Google Map SDK for iOS in which i am not able to rotate Map like below.

For Eg. MKMapview is able to rotate it with Compass Heading.

```
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

So My Question is is there any buddy help me out to find out how to Get that thing to be done in Google MAP SDK.

i have referred every thing about Google Map SDK i din't find any such property or any method to rotate Map according Device Compass value.

i have referred this link about Compass value but i could not find anything related to that.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like there is no direct step for this functionality in Google Maps iOS SDK. You can possibly achieve the required effect by combining the below 2 functions:

1, Occasionally read the current bearing using [locationManager:didUpdateHeading:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateHeading:). [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264838/use-native-ios-compass-within-an-app) to see the usage

2, When you get a new bearing value, set the bearing using [[mapView_ animateToBearing:x]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#bearing_orientation);

Answer (score 2):

By combining all the links in the above post, Here is an attempt to rotate GoogleMaps iOS SDK and it worked fine for me

First create a `CLLocationManager`

```
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

and use the `CLLocationManager`'s `startUpdatingHeading` method to call the delegate method   `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading` whenever there is a change in heading. Now you can change rotate the map according to the heading using the following code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    double heading = newHeading.trueHeading;
    double headingDegrees = (heading*M_PI/180);
    CLLocationDirection trueNorth = [newHeading trueHeading];
    [mapView_ animateToBearing:trueNorth];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 3.0**

Need to set up location manager and call startUpdatingHeading:

```
class NavegacaoRotaViewController: UIViewController ,GMSMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

...

```
self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
self.locationManager.delegate = self
self.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
```

Then include the following delegate method and you should be able to extract the heading angle from newHeading:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
            googleMapsView.animate(toBearing: newHeading.trueHeading)
}
```

**Obj-c**

Need to set up location manager and call startUpdatingHeading:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Then include the following delegate method and you should be able to extract the heading angle from newHeading:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
  NSLog(@"Updated heading: %@", newHeading);
}
```

Comment: How can we rotate the map back to default true North. I know if the compass is visible the user can press the compass and it will rotate the make to true north but how can it be done programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

**map rotation swift 5.0**

```
 func intlizeLocationManager(){
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    handleArea.delegate = self
    handleArea.settings.myLocationButton = true
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()

}

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    let head = newHeading.trueHeading
    map.animate(toBearing: head)
}
```